# Prevent Modal From Moving up and Down on Mobile?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered justify-content-center" id="modalInner" role="document">
    <div id="innerContentWrapper">
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>

      <div id="innerContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using a bootstrap mobile to make a lightbox gallery. On mobile, when users swipe it makes the modal jump up and down. How can I make it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try fixing its position in a media query specific to mobile views:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
 .modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  }
}
```